# How to open multiple amchart in multiple tabs on same GSP page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three tabs on a GSP page and I want to open unique amchart on each tab. But I am able to see only one amchart in active tab. When I click another tab, no amchartData is being displayed.

Comment: Can you show us your code or an example?

Comment: this is my fst amchart code..

Comment: yes u can see ,example like this bt i have unique amchart on all tabs ;;;......http://jsfiddle.net/martynasma/cmVBN/